# Python: Removing longer substrings of a string within a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, set

I have a long string. Of this string I have created a large set of substrings where each element may be a sub-substring of some other substring within the set. I am attempting to create a set of only the shortest substrings from my original set. Here is my attempt at a solution so far.

```
string = 'ABAAABAAB'
setA = {'ABAAAB', 'BAAAB', 'AAAB', 'AAB'}
setB = setA.copy()
setC = setA.copy()
for s1 in setA:
    len1 = len(s1)
    for s2 in setB:
        len2 = len(s2)
        if s1 in s2 and len2 > len1:
            setC.discard(s2)
```

I am creating a copy of my original set and iterating through the elements of `setA` then `setB`.  If one of those elements is a substring of the other element, I discard the longer element. The runtime of my solution increases greatly as the elements of `setA` increase due to use of nested loops. Is there a solution with lower time complexity?

Comment: Can you show for this example what you would like to be in `setC` at the end?  
My initial thought of how to make it more efficient is to use a sorted version (maybe by length of the strings?) of `setA` stored in a list instead of keeping it as a set (unsorted).

Comment: Sure, `setC` would be `{'AAB'}`. I'm unsure creating a list would work however, as I first created `setA` from a union of two other sets.

Comment: From the anwer @blhsing posted you can use the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function to sort a set and convert it into a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through `setA` from the shortest string to the longest, and add a given string to `setC` only if none of the possible substrings of the string is already in `setC`. You can generate all possible substrings from a string by iterating a starting index through the length of the string, and iterating the size of the substring from 1 to the remaining length of the string from the current starting index, and then using the starting index and the substring length to slice the string:

```
setC = set()
for s in sorted(setA, key=len):
    if not any(s[i: i + n + 1] in setC for i in range(len(s)) for n in range(len(s) - i)):
        setC.add(s)
```

`setC` becomes:

```
{'AAB'}
```

This improves the overall time complexity from *O(n^2)* of your solution to *O(n log n)*.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. Do you think you could elaborate a little bit on how your code determines that none of the substrings of the string are in `setC`?

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've added explanations to how all possible substrings are generated. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To make the substring searching algorithm @blhsing posted a little easier to read, you can just separate out the steps into their own loops. This is the same logic just not inside one line.

```
setC = set()
sortedList = sorted(setA, key=len)
for substring in sortedList:
    if not substring_in_set(substring, set3):
        setC.add(substring)


# Checks whether the subtrings is in the set 
# and returns True or False
def substring_in_set(substring, set):
    for i in range(len(substring)):
        for n in range(len(substring) - i):
            if substring[i: i + n + 1] in set:
                return True
    return False
```